# Symfony2 - Login Form that also asks for an account

Tags: security, symfony

I'm developing a web site with symfony2.1, one of its requirements is that a username has an account associate to it, so in the login form I ask for three fields the account, the username and the password.

I already modify the form, but I need to modify the login_check to take in account the new field (account), but the only documentation that I find,  assumes the username is always unique but in my case I can have a repeated username:

account: companya
username: admin

account: companyb
username: admin

```
#security.yml
form_login:
    check_path: /user/login_check
    login_path: /user/login
```

Any ideas how I can implement this?

---

Update:

I found the answer in this [forum post](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=38026), I also need to implement AbstractAuthenticationListener and new token to handle the new field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have requirements that are not covered by the "standard way" a framework provides, you have two approaches:

1. Do it on your own: Skip the build in security component and implement something on your own. In the end, you can always create a "normal" form, code the logic yourself and then set the session or the cookie.
2. Modify the security component. You would need to understand how it works and then dig into the [User Providers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) and [Authentication Providers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html). Have a look at the [cookbooks in the Security section of the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html).

I would go for number two if you "want to do it right" and number one if you just want to get the job done.

Comment: The answer is number two, I had to implement a User Provider and Authentication Provider two handle correctly extra fields in the login form. Thanks.